# Laravel 5.1 utf-8 saving to database

Tags: unicode, utf-8, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to save a record to database.
When get value from input and save it to database there is no problem, like :

> $request->input('name') is an input with value of 'سلام'

```
$provider->name = $request->input('name');
$provider->copyright_email = 'test@yahoo.com';
$provider->save();
```

But when i try give value from my controller problem appears.
Name will save '?' into database :

```
$provider->name = 'سلام';
$provider->copyright_email = 'test@yahoo.com';
$provider->save();
```

I've already added this code to config/database.php :

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_persian_ci',
```

Comment: Is your IDE/Text editor configured to use UTF-8?

Comment: @JaviStolz Thanks for replay. Yes. I'm using phpstorm and as you can see link below encoding configured to utf-8
[picture](http://imgur.com/soX7f1z)

Comment: read this https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-encodings.html

Comment: Where did you save this file? in your controller ? the file that contain "$provider->name = 'سلام';" , if yes, does your controller file is uni-coded? can you try to create the new file with Atom editor and try ?

Comment: @Shoully Thanks for replay. Yeah ! Just opened file with notepad++ and set it to encode utf-8 and after saving there was no problem. Don't know if i must do this manually for every single file which i use in my project, actually the picture and code i attached just was a test.

Comment: No, you don't have to do it manually, It's just your file was created with that character set, you can config PHPstorm to create any new file with utf-8 like @patricio said in the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. config you database file to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Check the file `config/database.php` :

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

2. Make sure your Mysql databases is set to `utf8` and MySQL’s `utf8mb4` is better
3. Make sure your file character set to `UTF-8 without BOM`

I personally think you problem in you IDE, try to use Atom.

Comment: "**1. ...**": Collation is only sorting algorithm, hence not relevant.  "**2. ...**": is already, as OP mentioned Databese is operating sometimes. "**3. ...**": thanks, that was OP's real issue.

Answer (score 1):

config your database file to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Check the file config/database.php :

'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

Answer (score 1):

im problem
use

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

**not work**

but use into migration

```
$table->charset = 'utf8';
$table->collation = 'utf8_persian_ci';
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the accepted answer dose not help me. 
Here how i solved the issue in this way:

Go to your table in your DB, check the 'Collation', change it to :

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Apply this to each field in the table.

This may help somebody. :)

Answer (score 0):

also you can use below code for setting utf8
->charset('utf8')