# Eloquent condition not detecting accented letters in where condition

Tags: laravel

In my web application I have locations and every location has `company_id` and I don't want to have same names of location in same company. So I made this:

```
$name = $request->get('name');
$location = Location::find($id);
if ($location->name != $name) {
    $old_location = Location::where('company_id', $location->company_id)
        ->where('name', $name)
        ->first();
    if ($old_location) {
        $errors = ['name' => trans('asset.location').' '.$name.' 
        '.trans('message.already_exists')];
            return back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I have `Service` location and want to change it's name to `Šervice` it will not let me to do it. I have no location that is named like that. If condition goes through but in eloquent search it fails. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have correctly specfied the charset in config file. like

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

src: [Laravel 5.1 utf-8 saving to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867172/laravel-5-1-utf-8-saving-to-database)

**AND**

I think, you must use the laravel validation here. So it could validate the request before processing.

```
Validator::extend('uniqueLocationInCompany', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $count = DB::table('locations')->where('name', $value)
                                ->where('company_id', $parameters[0])
                                ->count();

    return $count === 0;
});
```

You could then access this new rule in validator function:

```
'name' => "uniqueLocationInCompany:{$request->company_id}"
```

For more awareness on how should we implement validation in laravel you should follow the documentation here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: charset is like that, the problem was in collation, I provided the answer. Where can I put that Validatior::extend code? In what file?

Comment: In App\Providers\AppServiceProvider > boot()

Comment: @Nemanja please mark this if you think it helps to solve your issue.

Comment: I just did, it really helped me to find solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102371/sql-doesnt-differentiate-u-and-%C3%BC-although-collation-is-utf8mb4-unicode-ci)! and after reading the top answer I changed my code for `$old_location` to this:

```
$old_location = Location::where('company_id', $location->company_id)
    ->whereRaw('name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin', $name)
    ->first();
```

I used different collation for my eloquent where condition, and it's working flawlessly.