# Insert Arabic Issue to MS Sql Server laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to insert an arabic string to my table, but it's shown like   `ØªØ³Øª`.

I have tried to insert to the database table using eloquent and query builder, but the same issue is occurred.

```
DB::connection('ticketingsystem_new')->insert("Insert INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo]. 
[Table] (Reason,Feeling) VALUES (N'{$request->reason}','{$request->feeling}')");
```

The column data type is NVARCHAR(n).

Note : When I tried to insert an Arabic to this table directly on SQL management studio it works fine, but when using laravel framework it shows as ØªØ³Ø

Comment: Is your column datatype `NVARCHAR(n)`?

Comment: Yes,  it is NVARCHAR(n)

Comment: Tbh, I don't know about laravel, but since you are using parameters I think all what you need is to declare them as a unicode string.

Comment: Check out in `config/database.php` _'charset'   => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',_ See [this post as it may helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867172/laravel-5-1-utf-8-saving-to-database). Also you don't need the `N` prefix since you're passing a parameter.

Comment: I have set  'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci' but the same issue exist

Comment: your reason is in arabic or feeling too?

Comment: When I tried to insert an Arabic to this table   directly  on SQL management studio  it works fine ,  but when using laravel framework     it shows as ØªØ³Øª

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your PHP connection is properly configured.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'servername'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
      ------->  'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

and

```
DB::connection('ticketingsystem_new')->insert("Insert INTO [DatabaseName].[dbo]. 
[Table] (Reason,Feeling) VALUES (N'{$request->reason}','{N'$request->feeling}')");
```

or you can try with

```
$query = "[DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table] (Reason,Feeling) VALUES ";
   $query .= '(';
   $query .= "N'" . $request->reason . "', ";
   $query .= "N'" . $request->feeling . "'";
   $query .= ')';
```

Comment: I have set this configuration before   , but the same issue exist

Comment: what's your tds version?

Comment: TDS version  is 7.4  MS SQL server 2016

Answer (score 0):

Solved by  Upgrade laravel version,  I was using 5.1